# How to create an Photo Album in Facebook Using API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, photo

How to create like this  ?
 Users from my website  can Upload image to their FB page. 
for example : myfbcover.com

I uploaded these files (https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) .
Now what to Next ?
Please help me !

Answer (score 5):

Basic example:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
    'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

  //Create an album
  $album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'Album desc',
        'name'=> 'Album name'
  );
  $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

  //Get album ID of the album you've just created
  $album_uid = $create_album['id'];

  //Upload a photo to album of ID...
  $photo_details = array(
    'message'=> 'Photo message'
  );
  $file='app.jpg'; //Example image file
  $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

  $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
}
```

This is just an exmaple. You could find lots of sources on googling.
Hope it helps you get started

Comment: Does i need to Copy this Code and Paste in my Index.php ?                 
Is there any code before "$facebook = new Facebook(array(
" as Header File like "reqiure(facebook.php)" etc ?

Comment: require_once 'facebook-php-sdk-master'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'      => '',
    'secret'     => '',
    'fileUpload' => true
));
....

Comment: it is a shame this answer hasn't been selected as correct... so lets give it a thumbs up